# Alternative for Salesforce classic Tagging feature in Lightning

Tags: administration, system-admin

I have used tags in Salesforce classic. Now our project has shifted to lightning and lightning doesn't support tags. Is there any way in lightning through which I can achieve the functionality of Salesforce classic tags.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to reflect that Topics are not fully supported in LEX in Summer 17**

Topics are pretty much the new Tags. Topics are part of the standard navigation for Lightning Communities.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=basics_topics_records_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0

It seems like there are a few people talking about how to migrate your old Tags to Topics from back when Topics were introduced:

http://thewizardnews.com/2014/03/06/salesforce-spring14-migrating-public-tags-to-topics/

Sadly, this is not the complete answer as support for them seems to be limited in LEX for internal SF. They are available in the record feed (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_chatter_topics_in_lightning.htm), but not on the record page.

Comment: Thanx for your vital time @Aidan. but Topics are not yet available in lightning

Comment: @AmolJadhav OMG, sorry about that. They are a big part of Lightning Communities. So I assumed that they were in LEX for internal SF. Never assume anything about LEX :( Some partial support here https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_chatter_topics_in_lightning.htm

Comment: Anything else there in Lightning which can fulfill my requirement.